# Python: Kill sleeping thread

Tags: multithreading, python-3.6

I'm looking for ways to end a thread that is handling alarms.
Right now I make use of threads started via `concurrent.futures.thread.ThreadPoolExecutor` and I have one thread that simply waits to be given a `datetime.datetime` object through one `queue.Queue`, sleeps until the time specified in the datetime object is reached and then sends an alarm through another queue.

Since alarms will be scheduled repeatedly and the program is expected to run on a longer time scale, I don't want to make use of solutions like `threading.Timer` or `asyncio.create_task`, since they spawn new threads for each scheduled alarm. Is there a way to end/kill the sleeping thread prematurely or is there a better alternative for scheduling alarms than using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and a continuously sleeping thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I cannot find the question with the answer I ended up using anymore, but basically, I modified the `timeout` value to be the time I want to sleep. In combination with `block=True`, my script either gets another item from the queue or throws an `Empty` exception once the timeout is reached and I can continue as if my script just woke up from sleep.